# SSL error in push notification

Tags: php

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
(Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"
 - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject9\simplepush.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 5 Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"
- did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

How it can solve?
i removed the semicolon from *php.ini* but error not changed.

Comment: restart httpd? not clear

Comment: apache  restarted. but still have the problem

Comment: You removed the semicolon from where exactly. Run 'php -m' to list the modules and check for 'openssl'.

Comment: i run this command but the openssl not listed. How it can solve?